# use icon on ToolbarAndroid react native

Tags: react-native

```
       <ToolbarAndroid
        ....
        logo={require('./hawk.png')}
        />
```

How can I use [vector icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons). instead of png?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this.

```
    import {ToolbarAndroid} from 'react-native';
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

    ...

    action() {
        //code
    }

    ...

    <ToolbarAndroid>
      <Icon name="nameOfIcon" size={26} color="black" style={{margin: 10}} onPress={this.action.bind(this)}/>
    </ToolbarAndroid>
```

You can use size, color, name or style based on your requirement.

Comment: the icon is placed to the right of title. how to make it go left?